# C couldn't read a file

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, io

I have a homework about decrypting the secret message from a file. I need to read the file and convert the characters for decrypting but I couldn't even start the decrypt_and_print(char*) function.To test it I put control line but when I run the code it is not writing anything and it is not finishing the process. I don't know why is it happening I'm kinda new at c. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void decrypt_and_print(char*);
int main(){
        char* file_name = "/home/baran/hw4/encrypted_p1.img";
        decrypt_and_print(file_name);
        return 0;
}
void decrypt_and_print(char* file_name){
        FILE *f = fopen(file_name,"r");
        if(f == NULL){
                printf("Couldn't open file!");
        }else{
                printf("File opened sucesfully!");
        }
        char a;
        fscanf(f,"%ch",&a);
        while(fscanf(f,"%ch",&a) == 1){
                switch(a){
                        case '0':{printf(" ");break;}
                        case '1':{printf("-");break;}
                        case '2':{printf("_");break;}
                        case '3':{printf("|");break;}
                        case '4':{printf("/");break;}
                        case '5':{printf("\\");break;}
                        case '6':{printf("O");break;}
                        default:printf("\n");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide the full path for the filename.

Comment: Put newlines at the end of those debug strings to flush the output.  Mega-Dupe:(

Comment: `while(1)` is a pretty good indication that you're stuck in a loop.  `fscanf` is probably not reading any data (it already hit the end of the file), and the value left in a is greater than 6, so none of the cases are getting hit.  Check the value returned by fscanf.

Comment: eg, replace `fscanf() while(1) { ... fscanf ...` with the simpler `while( fscanf(...) == 1) { `

Comment: You don't have `break;` statements at the end of the cases, so they'll all fall through to the following cases. Is that intentional?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I changed the path as you say but nothings changed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are right but my program doesn't even prints control0. So actually i'm not even running the while loop, there must be something else I have to figure out before while loop.

Comment: @BaranSAHİN The fact that you see no output does not mean that the printf was not executed.  You are stuck in the loop and the io buffers have not been flushed.  Call `fflush` before you start the loop.

Comment: Or, add a default case that prints something, and you will quickly fill the buffer and generate output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell should i write fflush(f); right before while loop ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't fflush before the loop.  Instead, you should fix all the other issues that have been brought up.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I changed the code as you say and we take step. Now it prints the control0 control1 and opens the file successfully but nothing else program just terminated after printing these control things. I edited the new code.

Comment: It would appear that none of your input contains integers between 0 and 6.  Your edited code discards the first value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited the content of encrypted_p1.img what could be the problem

Comment: Chances are good that a file named `*.img` is not text data, so using `%d` with scanf is the wrong way to read it.

Comment: You'll want `break` statements inside your case to avoid fallthru.

Comment: Ah.  If your input looks like "111324", then scanf with %d is going to read very large integers.  You ought to stop using scanf and just use `fgetc` so that you only read one char at a time.

Comment: You want to read characters or digits, but you are using code to read numbers. These are not the same thing.

Comment: Firstly I edited code as you say and now it works thanks for your helps. You are right I am just trying to read integers but in the end I understand that these are not integers. These are all characters so I changed %d parts with %ch and type of "value a" as a char now it is working.

Comment: You don't want to do `fscanf()` followed by `while( 1 == fscanf)`  That first scanf is going to consume data (which you then ignore).   Just read inside the `while` condition, and nowhere else.  And I strongly encourage you to stop using the scanf family and just use `fgetc` instead.  You will spend many, many, many hours debugging stupid scanf format string errors, and those hours will contribute nothing you learning C.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, a format string of `%ch` requires that each character in the input file must be followed by a 'n'.  Suggest changing the format string to `%c`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses a valid format string in call to `fscanf()`
3. performs the desired functionality
4. informs the user, via `stderr`, when cannot open file
5. trails the format strings in `printf() with '\n' so each character is on a new line
6. prints the numeric value of any characters not already processed in the `switch()` statement.
7. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
8. documents why the `stdlib.h` header file is being included
9. properly exits if the call to `fopen()` fails, rather than trying to read from the (unopened) file

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

void decrypt_and_print(char*);

int main( void )
{
        char* file_name = "/home/baran/hw4/encrypted_p1.img";
        decrypt_and_print( file_name );
        return 0;
}


void decrypt_and_print( char* file_name )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( file_name, "rb" );
    if( !fp )
    {
         perror( "fopen faiied" );
         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("File opened successfully!");

    char a;

    while( fscanf(fp, "%c", &a ) == 1 )
    {
        switch( a )
        {
            case '0': 
                printf( " \n" );
                break;

            case '1':
                printf( "-\n" );
                break;

            case '2':
                printf( "_\n" );
                break;

            case '3':
                printf( "|\n" );
                break;

            case '4':
                printf( "/\n" );
                break;

            case '5':
                printf( "\\\n" );
                break;

            case '6':
                printf( "O\n" );
                break;

            default:
                printf( "char: %d ignored\n", (int)a );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

suggest modifying so it expects an command line parameter with the file path/name rather than depending on a hard coded path/name

Suggest replacing

```
int main( void )
{
    char* file_name = "/home/baran/hw4/encrypted_p1.img";
```

with

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char *file_name;
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        file_name = "/home/baran/hw4/encrypted_p1.img";
    }
    else
    {
        file_name = argv[1];
    }
```